# How to check if any file or directory is not owned by 'root' through unix or shell scripts?

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I have a directory. let's day `/data01`. It has many directories, sub directories, files etc. I would like to check that the directory and all its sub directories and files up to the depth level, that it's not owned by `root`. I'd like a command or shell script that can guarantee that any sub directory or file up to the depth/last level is not owned by root. I check with the following command -

```
ls -lrt /data01/ 

ls -lrt /data01/*
```

But this failed somehow (I don't know how ) and some files came up as root by someone on cross checking. Need help!

Answer (score 5):

```
find /data01 -maxdepth $n -not -user root
```

use `find` command, the options and arguments above are quite self-explained, just be careful to assign `n` to the desired depth.

if you want to search until the last level, just delete `-maxdepth $n`.

use `man find` if you want to explore more functionalities

Comment: what's $n doing here ?

Comment: @basari66 it's the max depth number you need to specify, let's say you specify as 1, it will not explore any subdirectory

Comment: I have improved my answer

Comment: So you mean I should use find /data01 -user root to find out the files whose ownership is root. right ?

Comment: @basari66 yes. -not is just to negate. but you said `file`. actually it will be `dirs` and `files`

Comment: so if it returns nothing, I can get assurance that no files or dirs are owned by root

Comment: @basari66 yes, if you are afraid, you can `sudo chown groupname:ownername filename`(`sudo chown root:root filename` in your case) to change one deep file in the directory and have a try(in a not that serious environment, your pc for example)

Answer (score 3):

***Option 1:***

The easiest and better option is to use `find` as below,

```
find /data01 -not -user <user>           # Prints the out in console
find /data01 -not -user <user> > Output  # Redirect the output to file Output
```

*Note:* in your case replace `<user>` with `root`. use option `-maxdepth <levels>` if you want to limit the recursive check through sub directories. detail as per Manual : Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments

***Option 2:***

If you want to use `ls`, then combine with other command such as `awk` to achieve this, example as below,

```
ls -l * -R | awk '{if($3=="root") print $0}' 

# -R --> Recursively list through all sub directories
# if($3=="root") --> checks the 3rd position(owner user) in the ls output is "root",
# in your case use if($3!="root") , but you may need to grep out blank lines and directory names from the final output
# print $0 --> Prints the entire line when if block is true
```